# How to remove array's newlines and add an element at the beginning of it in Perl?

Tags: perl, fasta

First of I have to apologize for editing my initial post. But after I provide my code I did the question fuzzy.

So, I have this an array (@start_cod) containing lines separated by /n as follows:

```
print @start_cod;

tatatattataattatatttat
    cacacacaacaccacaac
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

I need to remove the newlines and add ">text" ONLY at the beginning of the array as follow:

```
 >text
   tatatattataattatatttatcacacacaacaccacaacaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

I tried:

```
 s/\s+\z//  for @start_cod;                     
    print  ">text@start_cod";
```

I tried also with chomp

```
chomp @start_cod;                      
 print  ">text@start_cod";
```

and

```
my @start_cod = split("\n",$start_cod); 
  $start_cod = join("",@start_cod);
      print  ">text$start_cod";
```

but I get

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa>textcacacacacaacaccacaac>textaattatatattataattatatttat
```

Any suggestions on how to handle this in Perl Programming?

Here is my code which works 100%.

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use feature 'say';


    my %alliloux =();

    $/="\n>";

    while (<>) {
        s/>//g;
        my ($onoma, @seq) = split (/\n/, $_);
        my ($sp, $head) = split (/\./, $onoma);
        push @{ $alliloux{$sp} }, join "\n", ">$onoma", @seq;

               }

    foreach my $sp (keys %alliloux) {
                   chomp $sp; 
          my ($head, $dna) = split(/\t/, $sp);  
          my @start_cod = substr($dna, 3);


    say  @start_cod;
```

Input file:

```
>name   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
>name2  acacacacacaacaccacaac
>namex  aattatatattataattatatttat
```

output after Perl run

```
tatatattataattatatttat
cacacacaacaccacaac
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Desired output:

```
>text
 tatatattataattatatttatcacacacaacaccacaacaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and add the code as a [mcve]?

Comment: `print ">text @start_cod";`  is working fine, except formating, I'd use `print ">text\n",@start_cod,"\n";`

Comment: @Toto im not looking for that but thank you for your response.

Comment: @Robert I didn't upload my script because it's working properly, and I want to manipulate the "stard_cod" array at the end of it, but If you think that I would be helpful I will do that.

Comment: @KGee All good. I was looking for a small complete program that shows the problem, so that I could just run it and then try to fix it. If parsing works, leave that out. I think I understood what you were asking (see answer below), but you could have gotten a faster answer with a [mcve]. See also [ask].

Comment: I see.... I tried to keep it simple :-)

Comment: @KGee: What about pushing your `@start_cod` on top of a header, like: 
`my @start_cod = ('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacacacacacaacaccacaacaattatatattataattatatttat');

my @outputWithHeader = ("text>\n");
push (@outputWithHeader, @start_cod);
print @outputWithHeader;`

Comment: @barbasa thanks for the answer but its not working it prints aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa>text  (then newline) cacacacacaacaccacaac >text (then newline) ... aattatatattataattatatttat (then newline)  :-(

Comment: When you say "it's not working", we don't know what "it" is. You need to update your question with the complete code that you are actually running.

Comment: @briandfoy Now I realized that It was a big mistake from my side to provide my code. I did my question so unclear. I will edit my question again and I will write my question from scratch.

Comment: It's not a mistake to provide your code. We can't help if we can't see what you are doing. Read the links @Robert provided.

Comment: You should roll back this question, and read carefully what I posted. You do not have an array with those elements.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do what you want:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @start_cod = (
    'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
    'acacacacacaacaccacaac',
    'aattatatattataattatatttat',
);
print ">text\n", @start_cod, "\n";
```

The `print` first prints ">text" and a newline once, then you get the `@start_cod` items on a line, and the last `"\n"` makes sure you have a newline after the last element.

Output:

```
>text
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacacacacacaacaccacaacaattatatattataattatatttat
```

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your answer.  It was not exactly what I was looking for as my desired output is:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      >text (\n)  
                                         aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacacacacacaacaccacaacaattatatattataattatatttat  (removing all the newlines)

Comment: @KGee Ok, I've adjusted the answer. That was the reason for asking for a [mcve] -- it clearly shows what you're doing, and what you expect. Saves a few rounds of comment ping pong.

Comment: No still keeps adding  >text and newline in each of my oupout lines. :-(   I believe that  newlines need to be removed and then to add the >text \n  in the first line only

Comment: We have no idea what you are doing or how you are getting your output. Update your question with actual code.

Comment: @briandfoy I  add my entire code as I asked to do, and I wrote what I did.  Im trying to convert @start_cod; which has this values
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacacacacacaacaccacaacaattatatattataattatatttat to        >text                            aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacacacacacaacaccacaacaattatatattataattatatttat                     In the Linux command I provided above I am obtain what I want but at Perl I want able to do so.

Comment: The original problem is that there is nothing in the array. Look at that first `split` line. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to see [Read FASTA into Hash](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1194592). It's the same problem and very close to the code I wrote before I read it. Also, there are [modules on CPAN that can handle FASTA](https://metacpan.org/search?q=fasta).

---

I think you want to combine the sequences that start with the same name, disregarding the numbers. The sequences shouldn't have interior whitespace. In your code, you are constantly adding whitespace. You even join on a newline. So, you go to the doctor and say "My arm hurts when I do this", and the doctor says "So don't do that". :)

When you run into these sort of problems, check the results of your operations at each step to see if you get what you expect. Here's a much simplified version of a program that I think does what you want. I've removed most of the data structure because they are complicating your process.

In short, read a line and remove the newline at the end. That's one source of your newlines. Then, extract the sequence and concatenate that to the previous sequence. When you `join` with newlines, you are adding newlines. So, don't do that:

```
use v5.14;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %alliloux = ();

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;  # get rid of that newline!
    s/>//g;

    # now split on whitespace, but only up to two parts.
    # There's no array here.
    my( $name, $seq ) = split /\s+/, $_, 2;

    # remove the numbers at the end to get the prefix of the
    # name.
    my $prefix = $name =~ s/\d+\z//r;

    # append the current sequence for this prefix to what we
    # have already seen.f
    $alliloux{$prefix} .= $seq;
}

say Dumper( \%alliloux );
foreach my $base ( keys %alliloux ) {
    say ">text $alliloux{$base}";
    }

__DATA__
>name  aaa
>name2  cccc
>name99 aattaatt
```

You don't need the intermediate array. You can build up your string as you go. You don't need to have all the parts before you do that.

Now, to figure out where you might be going wrong, do a little at once. Ensure that you've extracted the right thing. It's handle to put characters around the variables you interpolate so you can see whitespace at the beginning or end:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;  # get rid of that newline!
    s/>//g;

    my( $name, $seq ) = split /\s+/, $_, 2;

    say "Name: <$name>";
    say "Seq: <$seq>"
}
```

Then, add another step, and ensure that works:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;  # get rid of that newline!
    s/>//g;

    my( $name, $seq ) = split /\s+/, $_, 2;

    say "Name: <$name>";
    say "Seq: <$seq>"

    my $prefix = $name =~ s/\d+\z//r;
    say "Prefix: <$prefix>";
}
```

Repeat this process for each step. Then, when you come with a question, you've pinpointed the point where things diverge. Here's the same technique in your program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while (<DATA>) {
    s/>//g;
    my ($onoma, @seq) = split (/\n/, $_);
    say "Onoma: <$onoma>";
}

__DATA__
>name  aaa
>name2  cccc
>name99 aattaatt
```

The output shows that you never had anything in `@seq`. You are splitting on a newline, but unless you've changed the default line ending, you'll only get a newline at the end:

```
Onoma: <name  aaa>
Onoma: <name2  cccc>
Onoma: <name99 aattaatt>
```

Now there's nothing in `@seq`, so a line like `join "\n", ">$onoma", @seq;` is really just `join "\n", ">$onoma"`. You could have seen that with a little checking.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your response. The code I posted doing some functions such us remove the first 3 letters form each line, randomize the lines and my last step is to add only in the first line >text.  So your code provided changing the entire scope of my Perl.

Comment: I'm just trying to get you to the right data structure. I don't change the entire scope of anything, and despite your question, your code doesn't "100% work". I'm not writing your code for you; I'm showing you how to figure out your code. If you want to remove characters and randomize lines, you need to explain that in your question. You haven't said anything about what you are trying to do. Go back and spend two paragraphs without code explaining the task.

Comment: When I was talking about the scope I meant the output that you provided. I didn't want to offend you at all :-(.   I used your script on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_perl_online.php  but the output was not that I was looking for. In my script   I substituted the <DATA>  with my array that contains all the values,  I got  some errors such us **Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///) **

Comment: Of course you get errors when you change my working code to something else (that you refuse to show us). I'm not trying to get you the output you wanted. I'm showing you how your code is broken and how to go about fixing it. You are resisting help.

Answer (score -1):

The description lacks clarity of the problem.

By looking at the desired output the following code comes to mind. Please see if it does what you was looking for.

Even looking at your code it is not clear what you try to do -- some part of the code does not make much sense.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @start_cod;

while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    next unless />\s?name.?\s+(.*)/;
    push @start_cod, $1;
}

print ">text\n " . join('',@start_cod);

__DATA__
>name  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
>name2  acacacacacaacaccacaac
.
.
.
> namex aattatatattataattatatttat
```

Comment: I was asked to provide a code in order to get some replies even if I knew that I will confuse the readers. So make it clear what I want.  From my code, I have my desired values stored in the array named  @start_cod. I need to find a way to remove the newlines and add >text /n in the first line only.  In command prompt If I use this command  awk '{print $2}' FILE |tr -d "\n\r"|awk '{print ">text\n"$0}'  I will obtain my desired output. So If you could apply the above command in on  start_cod. array I will be obligated.

Comment: @KGee -- I've changed the code to desired array name `@start_cod`. The command you provided `awk '{print $2}' FILE | tr -d "\n\r" | awk 'print ">text\n"$0}'` will not produce desired output. `awk` reads files line by line and there should not be `\n\r` in read line (it stripped on read). As `awk` will read line by line on out you will get `>text` for each read line.

Comment: @ Polar Bear.  I tried the command and works 100% in both my pc and  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php.  Regarding your code above when I paste it on my script the entire code colors changed comments from blue became pink etc. I tried to find if any " " missing from the next unless line but I didn't find the problem. I'm sorry that I'm really bad at Perl.

Comment: @KGee -- you need to remove `__DATA__` and bellow (it is test data), also change `while( <DATA> ) {` to `while( <> ) {` - to read not from `__DATA__` block but from file specified on command line.